# Normals of exported Blender model (.fbx) are not correct displayed in gameengine (CRYENGINE)

Tags: game-engine, normals

You can see in the first picture that the normals of the left pillar are not correct displayed. This happens with all "subobjects" in the model that are duplicated AND mirrored. The model is created in Blender and according to Blender the normals should be correct as you can see in the second picture.
Does somebody know the reason for that and how to fix it?

- Blender 2.79b
- CRYENGINE
- Model has no texture - just the standard material
- Model exported in .fbx

CRYENGINE:
[image]

Blender:
[image]

Comment: Try to apply scale of the object in Blender in Object mode, object selected, Ctrl+A, then recalculate normals